# Why the performance of pyspark script doesn't improve with more number of cores and executors?

Tags: performance, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a script for binary classification by loading a pre-trained model. I wonder why when I try different combinations of num-executors and executor-cores, I always get approximately the same performance. Here is important lines in my pyspark script:

```
start = time.time()

# extract evaluation pairs
#
aug_comb_mldf =  dfml_partial.select('eventId').crossJoin(df_id_zero_aug.select('eventId').withColumnRenamed('eventId', 'eventIde'))

pt1 = time.time()

# feature enigineering
#
feats_titles = ["feat1f", "feat2f", "feat3f",
                "feat4f", "feat5f", "feat6f"]
augfldf = aug_comb_mldf.join(dfml_partial.withColumnRenamed('eventId', 'eventId').alias('a'), ['eventId'], 'inner') \
   .join(dfallaug.withColumnRenamed('eventId', 'eventIde').drop('id').alias('b'), ['eventIde'], 'inner')\
   .withColumn('feat1f', when(expr('a.feat1 = b.feat1'), 1).otherwise(0))\
   .withColumn('feat2f', when(expr('a.feat2 = b.feat2'), 1).otherwise(0))\
   .withColumn('feat3f', when(expr('a.feat3 = b.feat3'), 1).otherwise(0))\
   .withColumn('feat4f', when(expr('a.feat4 = b.feat4'), 1).otherwise(0))\
   .withColumn('feat5f', when(expr('a.feat5 = b.feat5'), 1).otherwise(0))\
   .withColumn('feat6f', when(expr('a.feat6 = b.feat6'), 1).otherwise(0))\
   .select(feats_titles)

pt2 = time.time()

# Make predictions.
#
aug_predictions = model.transform(augfldf)

pt3 = time.time()

aug_predictions_true = aug_predictions.select("eventId", "eventIde", "id", "probability")
aug_predictions_true = aug_predictions_true.filter((aug_predictions.predictedLabel != '0'))

# find highest prob
#
w=Window().partitionBy("eventIde")

aug_predictions_true = aug_predictions_true.withColumn("rank", row_number().over(w.orderBy(desc("probability"))))\
        .filter(col("rank")==1)\
        .drop("rank")

pt4 = time.time()

print ("pt1-start = ", pt1-start)
print ("pt2-start = ", pt2-pt1)
print ("pt3-start = ", pt3-pt2)
print ("pt4-start = ", pt4-pt3)
print ("total = ", pt4-start)
```

Here is the performance:

```
('pt1-start = ', 0.034136056900024414)
('pt2-start = ', 0.41227102279663086)
('pt3-start = ', 0.12337303161621094)
('pt4-start = ', 0.1068110466003418)
('total = ', 0.676591157913208)
```

Here is how I run this script:

```
spark-submit --master yarn myapp.py --num-executors 16 --executor-cores 4 --executor-memory 12g --driver-memory 6g
```

I ran spark-submit with different combination of four config that you see and I always get approximately the same performance.

Answer (score 0):

This --executor-cores means the number parallel threads it will run inside the executors.
But in python theres no concept of threading because of GIL (Global interpreter Lock) so it will not run the parallel threads.

So to improve the performance of your runtime i would suggest to play with more number of executor instead of increasing the number of cores.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My issues is that by increasing number of cores also, the performance doesn't improve.